# Tidying up application resources in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-management

Computer and user-specific resources for apps are apparently supposed to be stored in [C:\ProgramData and C:\Users\owner\AppData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276139/what-is-the-difference-between-programdata-and-appdata). Yet, I see Apps resources scattered all over.  For example, texlive found its way between Users and ProgramData after installing TeXworks. Inside C:\Users\user\, I have several apps related folders, such as .sagemath .ssh .texlive2017, Evernote ..., and scoop folders (cpp and LaTeX were created by me in the shown screenshots). Under Documents, I have Powershell folder containing a 'profile'. Shouldn't these be in AppData?

How would I go about cleaning up this mess? How can I prevent worsening the mess in future installs?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "Shouldn't these be in AppData?" - Only if the author of the program designed their application to store data in those directories.  Those locations are only recommended by Microsoft.  If an application does not store data in those directories there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I just found out Evernote let's you change the "local files" directory.